# How to test the most significant bit of signed or unsigned integer?

Tags: c, integer-overflow, twos-complement

Given a `clock_t` data type that is guaranteed to be an integer of some sort, how do you test the value of the most significant bit using portable C code?  In other words, I need the definition of this function:

```
bool is_msb_set(clock_t clock);
```

But here's the twist: you don't know the size of `clock_t` nor if it is signed or unsigned (but assumed "signed" is twos-compliment).

My first thought was to do this:

```
const clock_t MSB = 1 << ((sizeof(clock_t) * 8) - 1);

bool is_msb_set(clock_t value) {
    return value & MSB;
}
```

but the definition of MSB overflows if `clock_t` is a signed value.  Maybe I'm overthinking this, but I'm stumped.

Comment: just make MSB be `uintmax_t` rather than `clock_t` (and cast `1` before shifting obviously)

Comment: where did you get that it's guaranteed to be an integer.? <<Alias of a fundamental arithmetic type capable of representing clock tick counts.>>

Comment: `clock_t` can be a floating type. For that it will be harder to find the most significant bit, because `&` bit operation will not work.

Comment: You should use `CHAR_BIT` rather than `8` for the size of a `char` in bits (from limits.h)

Comment: @GreenTree: If I come across a port for which `clock_t` is a float, I'll give it its own implementation.  In all the systems I'm supporting (so far), `clock_t` is integer-like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we can first check whether `clock_t` is signed or unsigned, and proceed accordingly.

```c
bool is_msb_set(clock_t value) {
    if ((clock_t)-1 < 0) {
        /* clock_t is signed */
        return value < 0;
    } else {
        /* clock_t is unsigned */
        return ((value << 1) >> 1) ^ value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like.  My one embellishment: `const bool IS_SIGNED = (clock_t)-1 < 0;`, then use IS_SIGNED in the body of the function.  Probably compiles to the same code, though.

Answer (score 2):

Just test the value directly without a mask:

```
bool is_msb_set(clock_t value) {
    if (value < 0) return 1;
    return value >> (sizeof(clock_t) * CHAR_BIT - 1);
}
```

If the left side of `>>` operator has "a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined", see [C11 6.5.7p5](https://port70.net/~nsz/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p5).

Because we `assumed "signed" is twos-compliment`, I can just test if `value` is lower then 0, the most significant bit will always be set to one. If it is not negative, it's positive, and `clock_t` is signed then `>>` is properly defined.

If `clock_t` is unsigned, then `value < 0` will always return `0` and most probably should be optimized out by the compiler.

The code shouldn't compile if `clock_t` is not an integer type (ex. if it a `float` or `double`), because the operands of `>>` need to have integer type. So it will only work for integer types.

Comment: Right-shifting causes implementation-defined behaviour for negative values

Comment: Right.. Hm, what if I would `abs(value)` ? No, this will alter the value. So this will work only for `value > 0`. Well, assuming it's twos-complement, I could add `if (value < 0) return 1`

Comment: Could we conceivably have an integer type whose number of bits is not `sizeof(type) * CHAR_BIT`, because some bits are unused or reserved or used for parity checks or something?  I think it's consistent with the C standard for, say, `unsigned int` to have a maximum value of `2^29-1`, `CHAR_BIT==8`, and `sizeof(unsigned int) == 4`.

Comment: I think your answer works: if the >> operator copies the sign bit, your get all ones which, as a boolean is true.  If the >> operator shifts in zeros, you get 1, which is also true.  (And I think you can eliminate the `(value < 0)` test.)

Comment: `if the >> operator copies the sign bit` - I don't get that part. The `>>` performs division. I can't eliminate `value < 0` because doing `<<` on signed type with negative value is implementation defined. I totally believe there is an implementation that for example  `(int8_t)0b10101010 >> 1` results in `0b10010101`, ie. the sign bit stays.

Comment: @KamilCuk: to expand on your comment: for one implementation `(0b10101010 >> 7)` might return `0b00000001`.  For another, it might return `0b11111111` (if it extends the sign bit).  For the case you mentioned, it would return `0b10000001`.  But in each case, the result is non-zero, i.e. (boolean)true.  And if the MSB == 0, the resulting shifted value will always be 0, i.e. (boolean)false.   This is why I don't think  you need the `value < 0` test.

Comment: Implementation defined means it can return _anything_. It can be all zeros or all ones for all values. It is up to implementation. I don't trust it, I don't expect the implementation to return anything "meaningful". No, I can't mask it, I can't do anything after that. If `value` is signed and negative, `value >> (...)` can return a random number as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Ah - I see what you mean.  Got it.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is cast it to an integer which is guaranteed to be large enough (so, long?) and *then* do your test against `1 << ((sizeof(clock_t) * 8) - 1);`.

I would also start by asserting that `sizeof(clock_t) <= sizeof(long)`.

Comment: Why do you think `long` will be large enough? It certainly isn't on most systems...

Comment: @StaceyGirl is right: in this particular case (time.h on ubuntu), clock_t is 8 bytes.